# How can one determine the full model number of Samsung A13 phone from the unit itself?

Tags: samsung, android-12

Looking at the Galaxy A13 label on rear *(as advised by Samsung, pictured below)* or Settings > About phone, gives SM-A137F/DSN for two different models, one of which (light blue) is I believe SM-A137FLBVEUB and the other (black) ... who knows.

Where else should I look to find the full model number?

[image]

Comment: Look up the IMEI number?

Comment: No. That says only "Phone model: SM-A137F/DSN (Galaxy A13)".

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that is possible because most of the phones are manufactured and assembled at defferent places. Also the hardware is same for all the variants (color) it's just outer casing that is changed while assembling.

Also anyone can buy another color of chassis and apply that. So it doesn't really matter.

PS. That is the full model number you are asking for. However, if you want to go deeper you can look up the lot number on Phone's box or invoice (which already has the color lol) and talk to the Phone's company if they still have stored the record and willing to help you regarding this. Again it is futile and a lot cumbersome.